# Referral program in Eloquent : Self referencing table with pivot one to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

For a referral program I have two tables. `users` (with an `id` and some other columns) and `referrals` (with a `referrer_id` and a `referred_id`).

A `User` may have **many** referred users, and `User` may have only **one** referrer `User`. So `User` model should be like:

```
class User extends Model 
{

    public function referrerUser()
    {
        // There may be only one referrer user for this user
    }

    public function referredUsers()
    {
        // There may be many referred users for this user
    }
}
```

I read some messages about this, but I'm a bit confused about the right way to do this. So, how can I return these relations using `belongsTo` (for `referrerUser` method) and `belongsToMany` (for `referredUsers` method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrap the referrals pivot table. There is no need for that in a `belongsTo`-`hasMany` relationship. This works the same as any similar relationship, you are just referencing the same table. So your users table needs a column to store the `referrer_id`, then your model could just look like this:

```
class User extends Model 
{

    public function referrerUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'referrer_id');
    }

    public function referredUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'referrer_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

You may have to switch the keys around. I always get them confused :)